# Print specific array elements

Tags: python, arrays

I have some trouble with this code. I have that file which has 2 words, and I want to print the array elements that contain the words from that file

file.txt:

```
apple
apples
```

Python code:

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
a = ["ashdfas" ,"i like apples", "yes", "no", "apple"]

for line in f.readlines():
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if line.strip() in str(a[i]):
            print(a[i])
```

output:

```
i like apples
apple
apple
```

expected output:

```
i like apples
apple
```

I have no idea why my output contains 'apple' 2 times. Any ideas?

Comment: That's a list, not an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The duplicate text is caused by the code seeing the word 'apple' in 'I like apples' (I like **apple**s). For a solution, I would recommend splitting each item into words, and then checking for equality between the array and the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand what happened!